# Size of array function return size of int instead of array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof

out put is always 8! I am wondering where this number comes from and how can I get the correct size of the size of the array which is 6?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void cal(int a[])
{
    printf("the size of array is= %d\n", (int)(sizeof(a)/(sizeof)(int)));
}

int main ()
{
    int lis[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    cal(&lis[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array is a pointer to a datatype. `sizeof a` will result in the size of the pointer to the array. `sizeof *a` will derefernce the pointer and return the size of the datatype. `sizeof *a * numElems` will return the number of bytes in the array.

Comment: @ppeterka66 no it's not. OP: I doubt the output is 8, much less that this compiles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Why wouldn't it compile?  He's passing an `int *` to a function that's expecting an `int *`.

Comment: @JohnBode because `(sizeof)(int)`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  Ah.  Blew right past that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not calculate the size of the int array when all you've got is an int pointer. You will always get pointer size.

You can possibly try this(Not sure if that is a good idea):-

```
#define arrSz(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))
```

Comment: Your `#define` works only if `a` is actually an array. In the OP's code, `a` is a pointer.

Comment: I see because we can get just an int pointer we can not have the size. It helps alot. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept this, as, an answer if this helped you